# Python: Attribute Error When Importing Pandas From a Script

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas imports fail when I invoke a script from the command line. I can't identify what is causing this. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
```

**Error**

```
root@vultr:~/Repos/solomon# python3 lib/scripts/dummy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lib/scripts/dummy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/api.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 50, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 69, in <module>
    from pandas.core.generic import NDFrame, _shared_docs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 48, in <module>
    from pandas.io.formats.format import format_percentiles, DataFrameFormatter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 36, in <module>
    from pandas.io.common import (_get_handle, UnicodeWriter, _expand_user,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 484, in <module>
    def UnicodeReader(f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'excel'
```

Comment: Do you have a *Python* module (file called *csv.py*, or a folder called *csv* containing a *\_\_init\_\_.py* file) in your local folder?

Comment: Yup, that was exactly the problem. Dumb mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Did you interrupted pandas installation?

Try to upgrade

(first install pip if you don't have it)
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

then

pip install pandas --upgrade

Comment: I solved the problem. See my reply below. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Sounds good, Np. That would have been next step, check what init file you have mixed.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

It was because I had a directory named "csv" in the same directory as the run script. Stupid mistake. Sorry guys and gals.